# how to deal with features which are both numerical and categorical

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

what is the best approach to deal with features which is both numerical and categorical? take the following feaure X for example:

```
 X
 1
 5
 3
 0
 1
 10
 10
 7
 0
 5
 9
 9
```

In which X represents credit score which should range 1 to 10, and if X=0, it means for this instance, the credit score doesn't exist.

how should I deal with it while using models like random forest or logistic regression to do a classification problem? Thank you.

Comment: This is not a mix of categorical and numerical. But a case of missing value. Check out how missing values are handled, or what are the best practices for handling them. Anyways, this question is not suitable for SO. Try https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: To be fair it may not necessarily fit in the missing value literature either. Depending on the goal, having no credit score may be just as valuable of a state as having a credit score of 10. Anyways, why not just one-hot encode the credit score variable?